# Prove that su(3) has only two casimir operators without Gell-Mann matrices

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The su(3) algebra can be represented as
\begin{align}
[{X^{a}}_{b}, {X^{c}}_{d}] = \delta^{c}_{b} {X^a}_d - \delta^{a}_{d} {X^c}_b
\end{align}
with a constraint ${X^{a}}_{a} = 1$ and $a, b, c \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. Here, I denote with the Einstein summation convention.
Then, I can define an infinite family of contractions as
\begin{align}
{(X \cdot X)^a}_{b} = {X^a}_n {X^n}_b
\end{align}
and so on.
Indeed, we can see the traces of the contractions are all invariant tensors of su(3) with
\begin{align}
[{X^a}_{b}, {(X \cdot X \cdot \dots \cdot X)^c}_c] = 0.
\end{align}

However, there are only two independent invariant tensors due to the fact that higher-order tensors can be reduced into lower ones.

To see this, the textbook which I'm reading discuss the existence of some numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that
\begin{equation}
{(X\cdot X \cdot X)^a}_b = \alpha \delta^a_b + \beta {X}^{a}_{b} + \gamma (X \cdot X)^{a}_{b}
\end{equation}

The textbook says we have to prepare the antisymmetric tensor
\begin{align}
{A^{ac}_{bd}} \equiv {X^a}_b {{X}^{c}}_{d} - {X^c}_b {X^a}_d - {X^a}_d {X^c}_b + {{X}^{c}}_{d} {X^a}_b - {\rm Trace.}
\end{align}
Here, the trace of $A$ is understood as ${A^{ac}_{bc}} (= 0)$. With the antisymmetry, this also leads $A^{ac}_{cd} = 0$.

The textbook also says we can see by taking trace
\begin{align}
 {C^{n}}_{m} = \epsilon_{mac} \epsilon^{nbd} A^{ac}_{bd}
\end{align}
*itself* vanishes. If so, $A^{ac}_{bd}$ vanishes by solving the inverse relation ($\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita tensor with $\epsilon_{123} = \epsilon^{123} = 1$).

But I suspect this. Of course we can show ${\rm Tr} C \equiv {C^{n}}_{n} = 0$, but general elements ${C^{n}}_{m} \neq 0$, I think.

Is there any way to show ${C^{n}}_{m} = 0$? Futheremore, how can I show that
\begin{equation}
{(X\cdot X \cdot X)^a}_b = \alpha \delta^a_b + \beta {X}^{a}_{b} + \gamma (X \cdot X)^{a}_{b}
\end{equation}
holds?

I'd like to show these facts only with the algebra, not with an explicit matrix representation.

**EDIT**:
Although I don't understand this yet, but I claim that the reduction may not be sufficient to show that there are only two Casimir operators.
The Casimir operators are given by $C_2 = {(X \cdot X)}^{a}_{a}, C_3 = {(X \cdot X \cdot X)^a}_a$.
However, given the reduction we see that
\begin{align}
{(X \cdot X \cdot X)^a}_a = 3\alpha + \beta + \gamma C_2
\end{align}
which means $C_3 \equiv {(X \cdot X \cdot X)^a}_a$ is not independent of $C_2$. Since constant numbers commute with any operator, the zeroth order Casimir operator should be defined as $C_0 = 1$. Hence if the above reduction is true, this leads
\begin{align}
C_3 = (3 \alpha + \beta )C_0 + \gamma C_2,
\end{align}
thus $C_3$ is not an independent Casimir operator.

Then I suppose that the above reduction holds only for $N \geq 4$-th order contraction.

Any comments would be appreciated.

#### **References**

*Ramond, Pierre*, Group theory. A physicist’s survey., Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-89603-0/hbk)(2010). [ZBL1205.20001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1205.20001).

Comment: Not directly related, but typically I have seen an appeal to the theorem of Racah to determine the number of independent Casimirs.

Comment: @Sal Yes, exactly. Hence we know that there are two independent Casimirs, but I'd like to obtain the explicit form of that. Usually discussions are done with Gell-Mann matrices...but I don't know discussions without any convention like the above one.